# hyperledger fabric checking endorsement policy responsibility

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

who is responsible for checking endorsement policy before committing to  ledger in hyperledger fabric? Orderer Service or committing peers?
In https://www.hyperledger.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/HL_Meetup_Blockchain_IBM__Mai_v2a-1.pdf shows that committing peers checks endorment policy. But in some videos told that ordering service checks it and after all checking builds block and sends to peer to commit it blindly.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering service does not perform any endorsement policy checks. The endorsement policy is normally checked by the client prior to submitting a transaction to the ordering service, and by each peer prior to committing.